# 1006 Connection closed abnormally error with python 3.7 websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm having the same problem as this github issue with python websockets:
https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/367

The proposed solution isn't working for me though. The error I'm getting is:

websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason

This is my code:

```
async def get_order_book(symbol):
    with open('test.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:
        csvw = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        DT = Data(data=data, last_OB_id=ob_id, last_TR_id=tr_id, sz=10, csvw=csvw)

        while True:
            if not websocket.open:
                print('Reconnecting')
                websocket = await websockets.connect(ws_url)
            else:
                resp = await websocket.recv()
                update = ujson.loads(resp)
                DT.update_data(update)

async def get_order_books():
    r = requests.get(url='https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr')
    await asyncio.gather(*[get_order_book(data['symbol']) for data in r.json()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(get_order_books())
```

The way I've been testing it is by closing my internet connection, but after a ten second delay it still returns the 1006 error.

I'm running Python 3.7 and Websockets 7.0.

Let me know what your thoughts are, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution:

When the connection closes, it breaks out of the while loop for some reason. So in order to keep the websocket running you have to surround

```
resp = await websocket.recv()
```

with try ... except and have

```
print('Reconnecting')
websocket = await websockets.connect(ws_url)
```

in the exception handling part.

Comment: that is the worst possible solution ever

Answer (score 37):

I encountered the same problem.
After digging a while I found multiple versions of the answer that tells to just reconnect, but I didn't think it was a reasonable route, so I dug some more.

Enabling DEBUG level logging I found out that python websockets default to sending ping packets, and failing to receive a response, timeouts the connection. I am not sure if this lines up with the standard, but at least javascript websockets are completely fine with the server my python script times out with.

The fix is simple: add another kw argument to `connect`:

```
websockets.connect(uri, ping_interval=None)
```

The same argument should also work for server side function `serve`.

More info at https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

Answer (score 2):

I might be a year late but i was just having this issue. No connection issues on my html5 websocket client but .py test client would crash after around a minute (raising 1006 exceptions for both the client and server too). As a test i started to just `await connection.recv()`ing after every frame the client sends. No more issues. I didnt need to receive data for my .py test client but apparently it causes issues if you let it build up. It's also probably why my web version was working fine, since i was handling the `.onmessage` callbacks.

Im pretty sure this is why this error occurs. So this solution of just receiving the data is an actual solution and not disabling pinging and screwing up a vital function of the protocol.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was starting to bash my head on my computer wondering why my sockets would close like this. Thank you very much

Comment: @Directory, would it be possible if you could paste the relevant code if something worked for you? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think they explained here: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

> it means that the TCP connection was lost. As a consequence, the
> WebSocket connection was closed without receiving a close frame, which
> is abnormal.
>
> You can catch and handle ConnectionClosed to prevent it from being
> logged.
>
> There are several reasons why long-lived connections may be lost:
>
> End-user devices tend to lose network connectivity often and
> unpredictably because they can move out of wireless network coverage,
> get unplugged from a wired network, enter airplane mode, be put to
> sleep, etc.
>
> HTTP load balancers or proxies that aren’t configured for long-lived
> connections may terminate connections after a short amount of time,
> usually 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this same issue. The solution by [shinola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58993145/12548449) worked for awhile, but I would still get errors sometimes.

To handle this I put the connection into a `while True:` loop and added two separate try except blocks. The `consumer` variable is a function that processes the messages received from the websocket connection.

```py
async def websocketConnect(uri, payload, consumer):
    websocket = await websockets.connect(uri, ssl=True)
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(payload))
    while True:
        if not websocket.open:
            try:
                print('Websocket is NOT connected. Reconnecting...')
                websocket = await websockets.connect(uri, ssl=True)
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(payload))
            except:
                print('Unable to reconnect, trying again.')
        try:
            async for message in websocket:
                if message is not None:
                    consumer(json.loads(message))
        except:
            print('Error receiving message from websocket.')
```

I start the connection using:

```py
def startWebsocket(uri, payload, consumer):
    asyncio.run(websocketConnect(uri, payload, consumer))
```

Comment: If ` ping_interval=None` does not solve the solution, for me what you suggest simply goes into an endless loop. : (

Comment: Once the program enters the loop it is supposed to run forever, trying to reconnect. This is why we start the websocket connection after the rest of the program is initialized and use callback functions to process the data. We also use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to separate the websocket connections from the rest of our application processes.

If you need to break loop after a lots of errors, you could add a retry counter in the `try` statement. So, that it retries for **x** amount of times before breaking the loop.

Answer (score -4):

I solved this problem by `uvicorn` the table with a [**`hypercorn`**](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/).

```
hypercorn app:app
```