# websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason Python 3.7 websockets

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, esp32

I have the same problem as this,
[1006 Connection closed abnormally error with python 3.7 websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101923/1006-connection-closed-abnormally-error-with-python-3-7-websockets) but my use case is different. So please help me out on this.

I am running a python websocket server. This is my code,

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "192.168.#.##", 5000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I connect to my server using a ESP32. The connection goes well and the  server echoes back the message sent from the ESP32 for about 30 seconds and the server stops at once. This happens regularly. This is  the error I receive `websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason`

My ESP32 code is as follows

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h> 
#include <ESP32Servo.h> 
const char* ssid     = "####";
const char* password = "####";
 
char path[] = "/";
char host[] = "192.168.#.##";

int M1A = 16; //motor drive input pins
int M1B = 17;
int M2A = 18;
int M2B = 27;
 
WebSocketClient webSocketClient;
WiFiClient client;

void connnect(){
   if (client.connect(host, 5000)) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");
  }
 
  webSocketClient.path = path;
  webSocketClient.host = host;
  if (webSocketClient.handshake(client)) {
    Serial.println("Handshake successful");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Handshake failed.");
  }
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  delay(5000);
 
 connnect();
 pinMode(M1A, OUTPUT); //configure as inputs
  pinMode(M1B, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2B, OUTPUT);
 
}
 
void loop() {
   String data;
  
    if (client.connected()) {
   
    webSocketClient.sendData("right");
    webSocketClient.getData(data);
    if (data!= NULL){
      if (data =="right"){
        Serial.println("right");
        analogWrite(M1A, 160);//pwm signal
        analogWrite(M1B, 0);
        analogWrite(M2A, 255);
        analogWrite(M2B, 255);
        delay(100);
      }else if (data =="left"){
        Serial.println("left");
        analogWrite(M1A, 255);//pwm signal
        analogWrite(M1B, 255);
        analogWrite(M2A, 160);
        analogWrite(M2B, 0);
        
      }else if (data =="forward"){
        Serial.println("forward");
        analogWrite(M1A, 160);//pwm signal
        analogWrite(M1B, 0);
        analogWrite(M2A, 160);
        analogWrite(M2B, 0);
        
      }else{
         Serial.println("stop");
         analogWrite(M1A, 255);//pwm signal
         analogWrite(M1B, 255);
         analogWrite(M2A, 255);
         analogWrite(M2B, 255);
      }
    }
 
  } else {
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    connnect();
  }
 
  delay(3000);
 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your ESP32 code that demonstrates the problem, because that's probably where the issue lies. Also - is the Python code you shared literally the code you're running? Because the code you shared should only accept connections from programs running on the same computer as it, and should not have ever worked with an ESP32 sending data to it.

Comment: @romkey I have included my ESP32 code in the question. I am running my server locally in my laptop. The ESP32 send and receives data without an issue. After about 30 seconds the server stops with above error